# Как реализовать анимацию как у status bar

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Есть фрагмент в котором горизонтальный `ViewPager`. По - центру тулбара находится стрелочка. Нужно сделать так чтобы потянув за эту стрелочку, сверху начал появляться новый фрагмент. Т.е. как и у `StatusBar`а. 
Если бы в главном фрагменте не было листалки, можно было бы сделать имплементацию вертикального пейджера. Но в данном случае не знаю с какой стороны подойти.

Comment: Вам код тут просто так никто не скинет

Comment: @Garf1eld, скажите, пожалуйста, что такое `custom-custom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

[SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

```
  <SlidingDrawer
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" // id кнопки за которую будем тянуть
        android:content="@+id/content"> // id контейнера с разметкой

     ...ваша разметка

    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Три удобных метода:

```
.setOnDrawerScrollListener();
.setOnDrawerCloseListener();
.setOnDrawerOpenListener();
```

+: Класс прост в имплементации.

-: *Deprecated*